# Ruby assignment hash

Tags: ruby, hash, key

I am working on a program to calculate grades and am using a hash of values to help with the letter assignments. My hash looks like this

```
LETTERS = {
  "A+" => 98, "A" => 95, "A-" => 92,
  "B+" => 88, "B" => 85, "B-" => 82,
  "C+" => 78, "C" => 75, "C-" => 72,
  "D+" => 68, "D" => 65, "D-" => 62,
  "F+" => 55, "F" => 40, "F-" => 25,
}
```

My question is how would I be able to assign, say, a 71 to a grade even though it is not an explicit value in the hash?

Comment: where to assign? Not getting you..

Comment: I'm trying to say if I had a 89 how do I get a B+ from that even though 89 isn't specifically in the dictionary.

Comment: for 89 why you want `B+` not the other keys? what is the logic of expecting the key `B+`?

Comment: LETTERS is a map of grades for assignments in school. If you get a 25 on an assignment you get a F-, but i'm trying to figure out how to make a 24 an F- also even though i don't specifically include it in the dictionary.

Comment: what you want when 21,22,23,24 etc ?

Comment: Since those are minimums, shouldn't "F-" correspond to zero?

Comment: Well, assuming that your hash defines numbers that are neither consistently at the top or bottom of the range (e.g. the range for B+ is 87-89 and in your hash you have `"B+" => 88`; the range for C- is 70-72 and in your hash you have `"C-" => 72`), then it's impossible. I don't know much about ruby, but I'm pretty sure it can't read your mind.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, in ruby we call it a hash - not a dictionary. You might do what you want with:

```
def grade(points)
  LETTERS.find {|_, v| v <= points}.first
end
```

Note: Find method depends on the order of the hash - the function above will not work correctly if the hash is not ordered (desc) by values. Also - you didn't say what should happen if points are, say, 20 (below any threshold). Currently it will throw `NoMethodError`

Comment: Alrighty, my bad. What would k,v be?

Comment: Key and value, nevermind..

Comment: In fact, you should probably do `_,v`, as the key itself is not used during the search.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the reason for using a hash here. In fact, the keys and the values in the OP's hash are the opposite, and useless.

```
[
[98, "A+"],
[95, "A"],
[92, "A-"],
[88, "B+"],
[85, "B"],
[82, "B-"],
[78, "C+"],
[75, "C"],
[72, "C-"],
[68, "D+"],
[65, "D"],
[62, "D-"],
[77, "F+"],
[40, "F"],
[25, "F-"],
]
.bsearch{|x, _| x <= 89}.to_a.last
# => "B+"
```

which turned out to be almost the same as BroiSatse's answer.

Comment: Nice one +1..Good use of `bsearch`

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer, but:
You could instead use a function that returns the grade depending on the value

```
def get_grade(points)
 return "A+" if points >= 98
 return "A" if points < 98 and points >= 95
 ... # etc
end
```

That way you don't have to assign each value a grade.

Alternatively, you could assign each grade an array of points

Comment: `[98...100]` is not an array of values, but an array containing a single range. maybe a typo?

Comment: removed it from the answer. It's been some time since I used Ruby, so I might have been mistaken there.

Comment: This would be much better with a `case` statement.

Comment: Also - you are returning if `points >= 98`. What's the point of checking again that `points < 98` in the next line (some will apply with a case statement).

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to encode the logic into a method using `case`. I'm adding this option because @blueygh2's answer was burning my eyes :)

```
def grade(score)
  case score
  when 98..100
    "A+"
  when 95...98
    "A"
  when 92...95
    "A-"
  end
  # and so forth
end
```

Using the non-inclusive ranges (with three dots) makes it work with fractional scores, but that may not be a requirement.